# Send array of values to controller using FormData Laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, form-data

I've a form from in which I' m getting opening hours and closing hours from end user.
User can input value for multiple opening hours and closing hours. The issue is I' m only getting first value of time in array but not the all entered values. How can I send array of values using Formdata to my controller ?

Blade

```
<form>
     <input name="closing_time[]" id="closing_time" placeholder="18:00" />
    .......
</form>
```

JavaScript

```
 .....
  formData.append("closing_time[]", document.getElementById('closing_time[]').value);
 .....
```

Controller

```
$closing_time = $request->input('closing_time');

dump($opening_time,$closing_time);
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: In js, the id attribute should be unique. If you have multiple `id="closing_time"` then you will get an warning error or get the first element

Comment: @sta Before that I was using form.serilize() and I was able to get all the values for "closing_time" but that was based on "name". Now I want to do the same but with ID, how can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting element by id where you got only single html element.

```
formData.append("closing_time[]", document.getElementById('closing_time[]').value);
```

get element by class name iterate a loop over elements and get values also store those values in javascript array and than append it to formData

Comment: I already have tried to make "closing_time" to "closing_time[]" but it throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [HTML Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2) the `ID` attribute should be unique in a page:

> This attribute assigns a name to an element. This name must be unique in a document.

If you have several elements with the same ID, your HTML is not valid.

Consequently, `getElementById()` only returns a single element. You can't make it return multiple elements.

There are a couple of related functions that will return an array of elements - `getElementsByName`, or `getElementsByClassName` that may be more suited to your requirements.